# RoR Password Protect Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, asset-pipeline, basic-authentication

I am trying to password protect the fonts sub-directory in my assets directory because of licensing etc. I have tried a few ideas for routing, but I haven't been able to figure one out yet.

As of now, if you use the route assets/* you can access the file, however I am trying to make it go to an http_basic_auth. I have tried setting up a controller called asset_controller with the http_basic_auth in it, but I can't seem to get the routing correct. Here is my code so far:

**routes.rb** (this obviously does not work...)

```
match '/assets/', to: 'assets#show'
```

**asset_controller.rb**

```
class AssetController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "admin", :password => "secret"
end
```

Also, this approach may be wrong. So, if there is a better solution please suggest one!

Comment: The controller would be called "AssetsController", not "AssetController", but it won't work anyways. You can't tap into the asset pipeline that way; if you define an Assets controller to handle `/assets/*`, you'll be *replacing* the asset pipeline completely.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is there a way to lock this down at all?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your intentions. What do you mean "for licensing"? If you want to use the fonts on your site, you need them to be publicly accessible, not password protected.

Comment: If you password protect your fonts directory then users won't be able to use them, making it completely pointless to have them. If you have them licensed to use on your website, then it is expected that users will have to download them so they can be used

Comment: Some fonts allow you to embed them on websites ONLY IF they are distributed in a secure format, translated: password protect the fonts.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to serve your fonts outside the asset pipeline. I would suggest creating a `FontsController` which serves the font assets behind whatever authentication mechanism you want to use. Serving binary assets and password-protecting actions of your controller are well-solved problems.